# Get textbox.text from nested gridview

Tags: c#, html, gridview, parent-child

I have a parent gridview with a child gridview

```
<!-- Parent -->
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%"  CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="SupplierReference" OnRowDataBound="gvParent_OnRowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                            <!-- Child -->
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvChild"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid" 
                            ShowFooter = "true" OnRowDataBound="gvChild_OnRowDataBound">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty"  ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>                  
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Qty")%>' />                                
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField >     
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>

                    </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelectQtys" runat="server"
                    CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("SupplierReference")%>' CommandName="SelectQtys"
                    OnClientClick = "return confirm('Add these materials to this task?')"
                    Text = "Add" OnClick="getQty"  ></asp:LinkButton>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to have a textbox that the user can alter the value and when they click add I want to be able to pull that text into the C# code and work with it.
I cant get it into my C# code.

```
    protected void getQty(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //After clicking "add"....
        //Do something here to get text from each TextBox1 in the Child gridview


    }
```

Someone please help before I lose what little hair I have left...

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void getQty(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //After clicking "add"....
    string s;
    for(i=0; i < gvChild.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        s = ((TextBox)gvChild.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text; 
    }
    //Do what you want to with this string

}
```

Comment: When I inserted this code I had 2 errors:  
1.  
string s = txt_YourTextBoxName.Text;  
error the name txt_YourTextBoxName does not exist in current context  
  
2.  
for x:Name  
Unrecognised tag or device prefix 'x'.  
  
Sorry, probably very obvious, but I am very confused....

Comment: Ups that x: thing is my mistake I'm used to simple wpf with xaml sorry. I edited my Code. If you have access to the Grid gvChild this should work.

Comment: Thanks again ---  I still have an issue... if I change the value in the textbox then WriteLn(s); it returns the old values and then reloads the page and returns the edited value to the original value.

Comment: Also getting the gvChild.rows... is proving to be a challenge outside of  protected void gvParent_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)